# Question about irreducible polynomials over a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

If a polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible over a finite field, does that mean the only factors are $\{1, f(x)\}$?

How would I go about proving a polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible over a finite field? A bit of searching on StackExchange showed me this:

> *Irreducibility criterion*: A polynomial $P\in\mathbf F_q[X]$ with degree $n$ is irreducible if  and only if
>
> 1. $P$ divides $X^{q^n}-X$;
> 2. $P$ is coprime with all  $X^{q^r}-X$, $\;r=\dfrac nd$, where $d$ is a prime divisor of $n$.

How would I apply this to $f(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ over $GF(2^8)$?

Comment: That degree eight polynomial A) is irreducible over $GF(2)$, but B) has a zero in $GF(2^8)$ and therefore is not irreducible over $GF(2^8)$.

Comment: It is the Rijndael/AES polynomial. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810861/11619) for irreducibility over $GF(2)$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If I want to prove irreducibility over GF(2^8), do I use GF(2) or GF(2^8)?

Comment: If it is not reducible, how do I factor the AES polynomial over GF(2^8)?

Comment: I am fairly sure that you were asked to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in the polynomial ring $GF(2)[x]$. Any mathematician would say this *irreducible over GF(2)*. But, this isn't the first time I've seen somebody asking for help to prove that it is *irreducible over GF(256)*. It isn't, but apparently there is a confused cryptoteacher out there somewhere.

Comment: It has a zero in $GF(256)$, namely $\alpha$. When we construct the field $GF(256)$ as the quotient ring of the polynomial ring $GF(2)[T]/(f(T))$ the coset $\alpha=T+(f(T))$ automatically becomes a zero of $f(x)$. The other zeros are the Galois conjugates, so the factorization over $GF(256)$ is
$$f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^4)\cdots (x-\alpha^{128}).$$ We have $\alpha^{256}=\alpha$, so the sequence of exponents that are powers of two stops there.

Comment: The problem is stated as "AES uses the irreducible polynomial f(x)=... for the Galois Field GF(2^8). Prove that f(x) is irreducible." I don't think he means GF(256) either, as I cannot find any information on the web about GF(256). I will assume he wants to prove irreducibility over GF(2) for now and ask him during office hours to confirm.

Comment: John, that sounds like a reasonable interpretation. You need this polynomial to define $GF(256)$. To that end you need that it is irreducible over $GF(2)$. I trust myself over Wikipedia on this any day of the week, because I have spent a lifetime working with these beasts :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes ‘$f(x)$ irreducible’ means the only divisors of $f(x)$ are $1$ and $f(x)$, up to a non-zero constant factor.

To apply the criterion to $f(x)$, which has degree $8$, you have to check:

- $f(x)\mid x^{256}-x$ and
- $f(x)$ is coprime with $x^{16}-x$ (via *Euclid's algorithm*).

Comment: Is there a name for this "Irreducibility criterion"? How would I divide something with such a large exponent?

Comment: @John You only need to find the remainder of $x^{256}-x$ modulo $f(x)$. That you can calculate relatively easily with the good old [square-and-multiply algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "only need to find the remainder..."?

Comment: The criterion is sometimes called *Rabin's irreducibility criterion*.

Comment: @John: Jyrki Lahtonen means you have to perform Euclid's algorithm. with $x^{256}-x$ and $f(x)$. Better do it  with some Computer Algebra software.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Isn't Euclid's Algorithm for Part 2 of the criterion? Would Maxima be a good CAS?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I evaluated "gcdex(x^(256) - x, x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1);" in Maxima and it gave two factors: one was an extremely long polynomial and the other factor was 1. Did I input something wrong?

Comment: @Bernard I ran the following evaluation in Matlab MuPad: gcdex($x^(16) - x, x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1,x$) and got a result of [1, gibberish, gibberish]. What does this mean? https://i.imgur.com/3S7ecFT.png

Comment: You asked to perform the *extended* Euclidean algorithm (gcd**ex**). $1$ is the gcd of the polynomials, the two other long polynomials are the coefficients of a Bézout's relation between your two polynomials. If you only want the gcd, I guess you should use the gcd function, not gcdex.

Comment: I guess the point of the criterion cited by John is that you never need to calcuate gcd's of polynomials. Divisibility is enough, and that is easier. True, we need to go up to $x^{256}-x$ whereas with gcd's it would suffice to check that $f(x)$ has none with any of $x^{16}-x$ and $x^8-x$. Eliminating the calculation of gcd's pays dividends here when divisibility is relatively straightforward to check.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That's right. If f(x) divides these polynomials, computing the gcd is the same as checking divisibility, but if it doesn't, it's much longer (at least by hand!). Furthermore, I don't know why John performed the extended version of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CAS for this low degree polynomial 
$$f(x)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1.$$
A pencil & paper solution follows:

First we calculate the remainders $r_k(x)$ of the monomials $x^{2k}, 0\le k\le7$, modulo $f(x)$. These are:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
k& r_k\\
\hline
0&1\\
1&x^2\\
2&x^4\\
3&x^6\\
4&x^4+x^3+x+1\\
5&x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2\\
6&x^7+x^5+x^3+x+1\\
7&x^7+x^4+x^3+x
\end{array}
$$
Producing this table is easy. You get $r_{k+1}(x)$ as the remainder of $x^2r_k(x)$ modulo $f(x)$. You only need to do long division, when $x^2r_k(x)$ has degree $\ge8$.

With this table at hand for referrals we can then easily calculate the remainders $p_\ell(x)$ of $x^{2^\ell}$ modulo $f(x)$. This task is tailor-made for [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Clearly we get $p_{\ell+1}(x)$ as the remainder of $p_{\ell(x)}^2$ modulo $f(x)$. Remember that, by Freshman's dream in characteristic two, we can square a polynomial from $GF(2)[x]$ term-by-term. When calculating $p_{\ell+1}(x)$ a term $x^n$ in $p_\ell(x)$ produces a term $r_k\equiv x^{2k}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_0(x)&\equiv&\equiv & x,\\
p_1(x)&\equiv p_0(x)^2\equiv r_1&\equiv &x^2,\\
p_2(x)&\equiv p_1(x)^2\equiv r_2&\equiv &x^4,\\
p_3(x)&\equiv p_2(x)^2\equiv r_4 &\equiv &x^4+x^3+x+1,\\
p_4(x)&\equiv p_3(x)^2\equiv r_4+r_3+r_1+r_0&\equiv&x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2+x,\\
p_5(x)&\equiv p_4(x)^2\equiv r_6+r_4+r_3+r_2+r_1&\equiv&x^7+x^6+x^5+x^2,\\
p_6(x)&\equiv p_5(x)^2\equiv r_7+r_6+r_5+r_2&\equiv&x^6+x^3+x^2+1,\\
p_7(x)&\equiv p_6(x)^2\equiv r_6+r_3+r_2+r_0&\equiv&x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x,\\
p_8(x)&\equiv p_7(x)^2\equiv r_7+r_6+r_5+r_4+r_3+r_1&\equiv&x.
\end{aligned}
$$
From this second table we see that

- The remainder of $x^{16}-x$ modulo $f(x)$ is $p_4(x)-x\neq0$ meaning that $f(x)$ is not a factor of $x^{16}-x$.
- The remainder of $x^{256}-x$ modulo $f(x)$ is $p_8(x)-x=0$ meaning that $f(x)$ is a factor of $x^{256}-x$.

Therefore we are done.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a non-zero non-unit element $r$ in a ring $R$ is irreducible if whenever $d$ divides $r$, $d$ is either a unit, or $d$ is the product of $r$ by a unit. So the set of divisors may be considerably larger and contains all elements of the field.